# Lebesgue measure identity

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A,B\subset \Bbb R$ non-empty. Let $E,F\subset \Bbb R$ measurable such that $A\subset E ,B\subset F$ and $m(E\cap F)=0$. Then $m^{*}(A\cup B)=m^{*}(A)+m^{*}(B)$. I need help with the proof of the inequality $m^{*}(A\cup B)\geq m^{*}(A)+m^{*}(B)$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since F is measurable $m^*(A)=m^*(A \cap F)+m^*(A \cap F^c)$ (1)
$A \cap F \subset E \cap F$ so $m^*(A \cap F)=0$ (2)
from (1),(2)  $m^*(A)=m^*(A \cap F^c)$ (3)

again because F is measurable $m^*(A \cup B)=m^*((A \cup B)\cap F)+m^*((A \cup B) \cap F^c)=m^*((A \cap F)\cup (B \cap F))+m^*((A \cap F^c) \cup (B \cap F^c)=m^*((A \cap F) \cup B)+m^*(A \cap F^c) \geq m^*(B)+m^*(A)$

the last inequality is because of (3) and the fact that $ B \subset (A \cap F) \cup B$
also note that $B \cap F^c $ is the empty set.

Answer (score 2):

STEP 1 (Establish a useful equality) :By the fact that $F$ is measurable we have $$m^*(A) = m^*(A\cap F) + m^*(A - F)$$
and since $m^*(A \cap F) \leq m^*(E \cap F) = 0$
we have
$$m^*(A) = m^*(A - F)$$
and by the same arguments
$$m^*(B) = m^*(B - E)$$

STEP 2 (Actual equality) From the definitions of the measurability of $E$ we have
$$m^*(A \cup B) = m^*((A \cup B) \cap E) + m^*((A \cup B) - E)\qquad (*)$$
For the first term we have
$$m^*((A \cup B) \cap E) = m((A \cap E) \cup (B \cap E)) = m(A \cup (B \cap E))$$
while the second
$$ m^*((A \cup B) - E) = m^*((A - E)\cup (B - E)) = m^*(B - E)$$
So now $(*)$ becomes
$$m^*(A \cup B) =  m^*(A \cup (B \cap E)) + m^*(B - E) \qquad (**)$$
The second term is $m^*(B - E) = m^*(B)$. So we seem to be on the right track. Continuing using the measurability of $F$ we have for the first term in the same way
$$m^*(A \cup (B \cap E)) = m^*([A \cup (B \cap E)] \cap F) + m^*([A \cup (B \cap E)] - F) \\
m^*((A \cap F)\cup(B \cap E)) + m^*(A - F)$$
where once again $m^*(A - F) = m^*(A)$ so $(**)$ becomes
$$m^*(A \cup B) =  m^*(A) + m^*(B)  +  m^*((A \cap F)\cup(B \cap E))\qquad (***)$$
where the final terms is zero because $(A \cap F)\cup(B \cap E) \subset F \cap E$ and we have proven the statement.

Comment: very nice mate.thanks!